# jQuery: selectize plugin

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I encountered this problem when I used selectize plugin with clone function in jQuery, see the result below after cloning.

[image: click this to show image]

```
$('select').each(function(){
  if ($(this)[0].selectize) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //$(this)[0].selectize.destroy();
    $(this).val(value);
  }
});


$('.item-row:first')
  .children()
  .clone() // copy
  .appendTo('#id_2');
```

All I need is to remove the unwanted inputs below.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the results you expect?

Comment: I just want to clone the first row of the supplier with 3 items sir, but when i click the add row button it results multiple selects.

Comment: I just want to remove the highlighted supplier with items

Comment: Try cloning `.item-row:first` first before getting the children and appending to `#id_2`. _i.e._ `$('.item-row:first').clone().children().appendTo('#id_2');`

Comment: nothings happen sir :(

Comment: Share a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) of markup for the screenshot in your question